# FaceBook Login Problem

Tags: java, facebook

I am going for an application which extracts information from facebook search, hence i require to login facebook. i have registered my application in facebook developers site and have got api key and secret key. in my code i am getting an exception when i am trying to login. Here is my code for login to facebook:

```
import com.facebook.api.FacebookRestClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams;


public class FaceLogin {
    public FaceLogin(){
        getUserID("username", "password");
    }


private static void getUserID(String email, String password)
{
        String session = null;
        try {
            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            http.setParams(new HttpClientParams());                             //http.getHostConfiguration().setHost("http://www.facebook.com/");
            http.setState(new HttpState());
            String api_key = "***********some key*************";                 
            String secret  = "***********some key*************";                 
            FacebookRestClient client = new FacebookRestClient(api_key, secret);
            client.setIsDesktop(true);

        String token = client.auth_createToken();
        final String loginId = "http://www.facebook.com/login.php";
        GetMethod get = new GetMethod(loginId + "?api_key=" + api_key + "&v=1.0&auth_token=" +token);
        System.out.println("Get="+get);
        http.executeMethod(get);

        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(loginId);

        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("api_key", api_key));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("v", "1.0"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("auth_token", token));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("fbconnect","true"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("return_session","true"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("session_key_only","true"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("req_perms","read_stream,publish_stream"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("lsd","8HYdi"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("locale","en_US"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("persistent","1"));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("email", email));
        post.addParameter(new NameValuePair("pass", password));


        System.out.println("Token ="+token);
        int postStatus = http.executeMethod(post);
        System.out.println("Response : " + postStatus);

        session = client.auth_getSession(token);                            // Here I am getting error
        System.out.println("Session string: " + session);
        long userid = client.users_getLoggedInUser();
        System.out.println("User Id is : " + userid);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
public static void main(String k[])
{
    FaceLogin facebookLoginObj=new FaceLogin();
}
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
>   processResponseHeaders
>
> WARNING: Cookie rejected: "$Version=0;
>   $Domain=deleted; $Path=/;
>   $Domain=.facebook.com". Cookie name
>   may not start with $
>
> Response : 200
>
> Jun 8, 2010 2:07:36 PM
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase
>   processResponseHeaders
>
> WARNING: Cookie rejected: "$Version=0;
>   $Path=deleted; $Path=/;
>   $Domain=.facebook.com".  Cookie name
>   may not start with $
>
> Facebook returns error code 100
>
> com.facebook.api.FacebookException:
>   Invalid parameter
>     - v -> 1.0
>           at com.facebook.api.FacebookRestClient.callMethod(FacebookRestClient.java:828)
>     - auth_token -> 004e90dc8818d5f0921d1065d24508d3
>           at com.facebook.api.FacebookRestClient.callMethod(FacebookRestClient.java:606)
>     - method -> facebook.auth.getSession
>     - call_id -> 1275986256796
>     - api_key -> f7cb1e48c383ef599da9021fc4dec322
>           at com.facebook.api.FacebookRestClient.auth_getSession(FacebookRestClient.java:1891)
>           at facebookcrawler.FacebookLogin.getUserID(FacebookLogin.java:81)
>            at facebookcrawler.FacebookLogin.(
>   - sig -> 9344ec75b74a0a87bcae645046d45da8
>   FacebookLogin.java:24)
>           at facebookcrawler.FaceLogin.main(FaceLogin.java:80)

Here may be the problem is for creating session, i searched for all the solutions on net but could not helped me to get login.

Please help me if you can suggest me some way to resolve this problem. i thanks to all your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going by intuition here:

- by reading the exception that you get, it seems that the problem is due to some "malformed" cookie, in fact it says "Cookie name may not start with $", which is the case for cookies according to [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)
- I see that you're using Apache HttpClient, which does automatic management of cookies, and supports various cookies specifications (see [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html))
- since you haven't specified anything, I suspect HttpClient uses by default RFC2109-compliant cookies, and maybe these are not OK for facebook.

So, you might want to try a different `CookiePolicy` in HttpClient, and see what happens.

p.s. please double check the exception that you copied and pasted above, because I'm afraid it's disclosing the value of your `api_key` and `auth_token`